# how to write procedure to add where clause dynamically in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to write the store procedure in mysql where I want to add "where clause"
dynamically 
I have written the Sp but Its Giving an error 
Please Help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudent(
  @Center varchar(20)=null,
  @Gender varchar(20) = null,
  @yrOf10 date= null,
@Designation varchar(20)= null,)
AS DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(100);DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(2000);

SET @Query = ' SELECT * FROM Student WHERE 1=1';IF @Center IS NOT NULL
     SET @Query = @Query + ' AND Center= @Center ';IF @Gender IS NOT NULL         SET @Query = @Query + ' AND Gender=@Gender  ';IF @yrOf10 IS NOT NULL   SET @Query = @Query + ' AND yrOfPassing10=@yrOf10   ';IF @Designation IS NOT NULL    SET @Query = @Query + ' AND Designation=@Designation';
```

Comment: WHAT ERROR? If you want help then give people the information they need, we are not psychic.

Comment: I am Getting This Error..#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Center varchar(20)=null,

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the @ sign in an object name http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html.

I don't know why you have prefixed everything with @. Did you start out with MS SQL or something?

Anyway to decalre a local var you use DECLARE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html